# Category Combobox and subcategory Binding Combobox

Tags: c#, json, uwp, combobox

I have a combobox category with 2 items ('usia' and 'serial') and when a user selects one item, for example: serial, it will display binding combobox containing serial subcategories.
XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="kategoriBox" PlaceholderText="Kategori" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="KategoriBox_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Usia</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Serial</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="usiaBox" PlaceholderText="Pilih Usia" ItemsSource="{x:Bind RatingList}" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="UsiaBox_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="serialBox" Margin="15,0,0,0" PlaceholderText="Pilih Serial" ItemsSource="{x:Bind SerialList}" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="SerialBox_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
```

Code:

```
private void KategoriBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedcmb = ((ComboBoxItem)kategoriBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
        if (selectedcmb == "Usia")
        {
            UsiaC();
                usiaBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                serialBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (selectedcmb == "Serial")
        {
            SerialC();
                usiaBoX.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                serialBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
}

private async void UsiaC()
{
    try
        {
                    string urlPath = "https://..../api-v3/Fetch/rating";
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {

                    };

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt");
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                    }

                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue.GetObject();
                        string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                        string name = groupObject1["rating"].GetString();

                        Rating rate = new Rating();
                        rate.ID = id;
                        rate.Name = name;

                        RatingList.Add(new Rating()
                        {
                            ID = rate.ID,
                            Name = rate.Name
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                    umurID = "";
                }
            }
        }

        private async void SerialC()
        {
        try
                {
                    string urlPath = "https://.../api-v3/Fetch/serial";
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {

                    };

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt");
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                    }

                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue.GetObject();
                        string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                        string name = groupObject1["nama"].GetString();
                        string slug = groupObject1["slug"].GetString();

                        Serial seri = new Serial();
                        seri.ID = id;
                        seri.Name = name;
                        seri.Slug = slug;

                        SerialList.Add(new Serial()
                        {
                            ID = seri.ID,
                            Name = seri.Name,
                            Slug = seri.Slug
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                    serialID = "";
                }
            }
        }

        private void UsiaBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (usiaBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
                Usia value = comboBox.SelectedItem as Rating;
                usiaID = value.ID;
                serialID = "";
            }
            else
            {
                usiaID = "";
            }
        }

        private void SerialBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
                Serial value = comboBox.SelectedItem as Serial;
                serialID = value.ID;
                usiaID = "";
            }
            else
            {
                serialID = "";
            }
        }
```

Usia.cs

```
class Usia
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
```

Serial.cs

```
class Serial
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
```

I have a problem, namely: I chose 'serial' on the category combobox then chose the subcategory. Then I chose 'usia' on the combobox category then chose the subcategory. Then I re-select 'serial' on the category and click the subcategory, then an error message will appear as shown below:
[image: error message]

How to handle it?

Comment: The screenshot is an error message when I select 'serial' category in combobox category and choose its subcategory, after first selecting 'serial' on the category combobox and selecting its subcategory, then selecting 'usia' in the category combobox and selecting the subcategory.
I have fixed the code

Comment: What is the exception? What is its callstack?

(You should be able to see it in the debugger, if you e.g. hover your mouse over the e-argument of the UnhandleException handler visible in your screenshot)